# Font Awesome 6 (beta) and dynamic icon name in Next JS

Tags: next.js, font-awesome

I am developing a website with Next JS. This is the first time I use this language and I still have a lot to learn.

Now, I have a Pro subscription to Font Awesome and I am looking to use their component directly in my project, as described in their guides.

https://fontawesome.com/v6.0/docs/web/use-with/react/

https://fontawesome.com/v6.0/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons

Basically, just using a component like this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={brands("google")} />
```

It works.

The problem, which I can't solve, is how to set the "google" value dynamically, in a previously initialized variable. I need that because this values are coming dynamically from a database.

If I try:

```
var example = "google";
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={brands(example)} />
```

Then I receive this error: "Only string literals are supported when referencing icons (use a string here instead)".

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way you import your icons uses a babel macro. It means that the referenced icon must be known at build time. It just won't work, because Babel can't figure out what icon should be imported, it can only be done during runtime. That's why it tells you that only string literals are supported.

So you need to use the [second method, explained in the docs](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons#add-individual-icons-explicitly). You have to have some kind of mapping between icon and the value from DB and then grab the relevant icon. Something like this:

```js
// not sure about exact import
import { faGoogle } from '@fortawesome/free-brand-svg-icons';

// you'd put all valid values that can come from the backend here
const myIcons = {
  google: faGoogle
}

// ...

const example = 'google';
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={myIcons[example]} />
```

The other option is to use `library.add`, [explained here](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons#add-icons-globally) and then do the same as above but instead of imported icon use a string, e.g. `google: 'fa-brands fa-google'` (again, not sure about exact value here).

Comment: A thousand thanks! I confirm that the global method works correctly, although less comfortable than the babel macros.

Comment: If this approach is published as a shared library, do you think it will tree shake (so that only icons used by the consuming app will be included in the consuming app's bundle)? or would all of the icons imported by the library component be in the final bundle?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm pretty sure all the imported icons would end up in the final bundle. You'd have to export a component for each icon, i.e. `export const GoogleIcon = () => <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} />;` and then the consuming app would import these, but then you might as well just not do this and tell the users to import icons directly.

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work?

```
var example = ['fab', 'google'];

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={example} />
```

P.S. It is recommended to use the `let` or `const` keywords with ES6.

Comment: Unfortunately not, as written in paolostyle's answer. Thank you for the ES6 suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Utils:

```js
const UpperFirst = (sentence) => {
    if (!sentence || (typeof sentence !== 'string')) return null
    return `${sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${sentence.slice(1)}`
}
```

React Generic Component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import * as solid from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import * as regular from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { UpperFirst } from '@utils'

const GenFontAwe = ({ isReg, customClass, nameIco }) => {
    if (!nameIco) return null
    const finalName = nameIco.split('-').map((cv, ind) => ind === 0 ? cv : UpperFirst(cv)).join('')
    const finalIcon = isReg ? regular[finalName] : solid[finalName]
    if(!finalIcon) return null
    return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={finalIcon} className={customClass || ''} />
}

export default GenFontAwe
```

Consume that way:

```js
<GenFontAwe nameIco='fa-folder-open' isReg customClass="h1 p-5" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).